# Does anyone other than PopCap sell Alchemy?

Tags: alchemy

I know that PopCap sells some of their games through third parties, such as Steam, for example.

Does any such third party sell [Alchemy](http://www.popcap.com/games/alchemy)?

Comment: VTC as off-topic since it falls under shopping advice and recommendation which is off-topic as outlined in the [FAQ]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as per the [meta] post, [Do we allow questions about where to buy things?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2707/4797)

Answer (score 1):

The only third-party I know of selling Alchemy is [Zylom](http://www.zylom.com). You can buy it from them [here](http://www.zylom.com/us/en/puzzle-games/braintraining/alchemy-deluxe/).

Answer (score 0):

As of March 2023 you can buy [Popcap's Alchemy from the EA store](https://www.ea.com/games/alchemy/alchemy).